# Writing empty table in a Geopackage of a certain geometry type using sf

Tags: r, sf, geopackage

I'd like to create an empty table (i.e.: no rows) in Geopackage but with a specific geometry type (i.e.: polygons).

The following code creates a simple feature collection with 0 features and 0 fields, but nowhere is the geometry type specified.

I looked to see if anything could be provided to the `layer_options` argument for `sf::st_write` but I didn't come up with anything.

```
file_path <- "example/mypackage.gpkg"

empty_table <- sf::st_sf(geometry = sf::st_sfc())

sf::st_write(empty_table, file_path, layer = "empty_table")
```

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat tricky; kind of a zen-like: the geometry type of layer that is not...

While I kind of fail to see the benefit of doing this (I am a man of limited imagination) it should be in principle doable at low level - utilizing direct SQL calls via DBI backend. I have used it successfully to create views - wrapping a spatial table in a kind of a star schema.

You would need to:

- connect to your geopackage as a RSQLite database; doable from R or even python if so inclined
- create an empty data table of desired structure
- create a record for your data table in `gpkg_contents` table, which is obligatory in a geopackage
- create for your data table a record in `gpkg_geometry_columns` which is again obligatory for a geopackage, and sets stuff like geometry type and CRS.

In the last step you should be able to declare your empty table to be of geometry type polygon or what not...

Comment: There are also a bunch of triggers in a GeoPackage which are taking care of integrity of the database. It is of course possible to create them manually with SQL but it is tedious.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a way to do it from `sf` because it seems to drop geometry type for empty geometries. But you can create a table with one row and then use SQL to delete all rows.

Example, here's a simple 1-row POINT spatial data frame:

```
> d1
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 0.1055935 ymin: 0.4832159 xmax: 0.1055935 ymax: 0.4832159
CRS:           NA
  Z                    geometry
1 a POINT (0.1055935 0.4832159)
```

Write it to a geopackage:

```
> st_write(d1, "empty.gpkg", "empty")
writing GPKG: substituting LOCAL_CS["Undefined Cartesian SRS"] for missing CRS
Writing layer `empty' to data source `empty.gpkg' using driver `GPKG'
Writing 1 features with 1 fields and geometry type Point.
```

Using the `RSQLite` package, make a connection:

```
> con = dbConnect(SQLite(), "empty.gpkg")
```

Delete every row:

```
> dbExecute(con, "delete from empty where 1 = 1")
[1] 5
```

And now when we read back it has zero rows:

```
> st_read("empty.gpkg")
Reading layer `empty' from data source 
  `/home/rowlings/Downloads/SO/empty/empty.gpkg' using driver `GPKG'
Simple feature collection with 0 features and 1 field
Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
Projected CRS: Undefined Cartesian SRS
```

And note `sf` has no clue of the geometry, although it is in the geopackage metadata table as "POINT":

```
> dbReadTable(con, "gpkg_geometry_columns")
  table_name column_name geometry_type_name srs_id z m
1      empty        geom              POINT 100000 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the `gpkg_geometry_columns` table and that was quite helpful